# React native maps not updating detail while zooming

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I've implemented React Native Maps and I have a basic  that allows me to interact with the map as expected.

I can pan North/East/South/West without a problem. But when I zoom, it doesn't update the finer details in the map like I'd expect.

My MapView is as follows:

```js
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={initialRegion}
    mapType={mapType}
    onRegionChange={handleRegionChange}
    onMapReady={() => {
        setRegionReady(true)
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    followsUserLocation={true}
    showsMyLocationButton={true}
/>
```

My initial region is:

```js
const initialRegion = {
    latitude: 56.55352329368351,
    latitudeDelta: 10.777170227627643,
    longitude: -4.6383764035999775,
    longitudeDelta: 9.564308412373066,
}
```

Anything obvious I'm missing here?

### Edit

This only seem to be an issue on simulators. Xcode/Android sims studio both show this behavior but physical devices seem to work.

[image]